# How i can disable a column from the lists' Quick Edit Grid using a JSlink which is linked to list view webpart

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model, csom, jslink

I want to disable the Title column from the Quick Edit grid, inside certain web-parts so i did the following steps:-

1- I went to a list view.

2- Edit the page

3- Edit the web part.

4- Under the "Miscellaneous" tab

5- I add a reference to the following JSLink:-

```
(function () {

      function registerRenderer() {
        var ctxForm = {};
        ctxForm.Templates = ctxForm.Templates || {};;
        ctxForm.Templates.OnPreRender = function(ctx) {
        var statusField = ctx.ListSchema.Field.filter(function(f) {
            return f.Name === 'Title';
        });
        if (statusField.length>0) {
            statusField[0].AllowGridEditing = false;
        }
    }
        ctxForm.Templates = {
            Fields : {
                'LinkTitle': { //------ Change Hyperlink of LinkTitle
                    View : function (ctx) {
                        if(ctx.CurrentItem.SiteAutomaticallyCreated != null && ctx.CurrentItem.SiteAutomaticallyCreated === 'Yes'){
                        var url = String.format('{0}{1}', "/Programmes/", ctx.CurrentItem.ID);
                        return String.format('<a href="{0}" onclick="EditItem2(event, \'{0}\');return false;">{1}</a>', url, ctx.CurrentItem.Title);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var url = String.format('{0}{1}', "/Programmes/Lists/Projects/DispForm.aspx?ID=", ctx.CurrentItem.ID);
                        return String.format('<a href="{0}" onclick="EditItem2(event, \'{0}\');return false;">{1}</a>', url, ctx.CurrentItem.Title);
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        };
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctxForm);
    }
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');


})();
```

but the Title field will still be editable inside the quick edit grid, while the other part of my JS link (`ctxForm.Templates`) is working well. so can anyone adivce how i can disable the Title field on certain web parts using JSlink ?? as seems this part inside my JSLink is not working well:-

```
ctxForm.Templates.OnPreRender = function(ctx) {
        var statusField = ctx.ListSchema.Field.filter(function(f) {
            return f.Name === 'Title';
        });
        if (statusField.length>0) {
            statusField[0].AllowGridEditing = false;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: John...do you need the Title to show in other places? If you don't want it at all, what I normally do is create a content type and set that column to hidden.

Comment: @jpollar in my case the Title column will be set automatically inside a workflow .. so i am already hiding it inside the content type. but on the list views i want to show it ,, but i need to prevent users from changing its value by disabling it inside the quick edit grid.. hope this explain my problem in a better way for you??

Comment: Found something that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John G,

Try something like this.

Reference: [Disabling a column in Quick Edit](https://chuvash.eu/2014/11/28/disabling-a-column-in-quick-edit/)

```
(function () {
    var overrideContext = {};
    overrideContext.Templates = overrideContext.Templates || {};
    overrideContext.Templates.OnPreRender = function(ctx) {
        var statusField = ctx.ListSchema.Field.filter(function(f) {
            return f.Name === 'LinkTitle';
        });
        if (statusField) {
            statusField[0].AllowGridEditing = false;
        }
    }
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideContext);
})();
```

Comment: i think the internal name for the column is LinkTitle and not Title.. please update your answer so i can accept it.. thank

Comment: wish granted. ;)